# Using an x64 assembler to reference memory

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I'm using this assembler: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly

Does anyone know how to encode a memory operand?  Say for example this ADD on page 457 of the intel x64 manual:  ADD r/m8, imm8.  I would have thought it'd be like 'ADD 0x1122334455667788, 0x01' but it says "Error: operand type mismatch for `add'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Intel assembly syntax, you need to use square brackets to denote that you are referencing the value at a memory address and also include the size information.

`ADD DWORD PTR [0x11223344], 0x55`

See "Addressing Memory" and "Size Directives" of https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html#memory for more information.

-- edit: fix answer to acknowledge it is possible to access memory directly.

Comment: I want to add that 0x01 to the value at address 0x1122334455667788, or is that not right?

Comment: You cannot add an immediate directly to a memory address; you need to use an intermediate register. Try:

```mov rax, 0x1122334455667788;
add qword ptr [rax], 1```

Also: make sure you use the right size (`qword`, `dword`, etc) for the add.

Comment: It says that you can use the R/M byte to reference memory directly in here? http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm.

Comment: @RyanBrown You can add an immediate to a memory operand, but  that memory operand is invalid. It's too big. Displacements are 32-bits even in 64-bit mode.

Comment: I tried cutting the address down to 4 bytes: ADD [0x11223344], 0x55  but I gave this message: Error: ambiguous operand size for `add'

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize that was possible. @RyanBrown I used `ADD DWORD PTR [0x11223344], 0x55` successfully.

Comment: Any idea how to specify a displacement address instead of an absolute?